# How do I use Lottie's onSegmentStart event handler?

Tags: javascript, lottie

In Lottie, what does the `onSegmentStart` event handler do? I can't find any documentation on it or how to use it. I would like to find a way to change `setSpeed` once a certain segment has been reached in the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
const animation = lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: '#container',
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  ...
})

animation.onSegmentStart = function() {
  //change your setSpeed here
}
```

Comment: But how/where do you define which segment?

Comment: To answer myself, turns out you cannot specify which segment. Instead, onSegmentStart will run the function whenever any segment starts. If you want to be able to capture which segment you are starting, you would need to use animation.currentFrame to identify what frame you are on when the segment starts, then use that to identify which. This only works if your segments don't overlap. Frustrating.

Comment: @Josh It's worse than that. For some bizarre reason `currentFrame` will be the frame within the current segment and not the animation as a whole. I'm a developer and I'm completely flummoxed as to why anybody would think that makes any sense. I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Are you sure? I haven't touched Lottie in a while but I believe I was able to make a function that allowed me to divide a Lottie into sub-animations that would let you define loops and exit points, all based on current frame. Maybe they changed it or maybe I'm wrong, I'll have to take another look at that code

Comment: @JoshSilveous I had to end up doing `anim.currentFrame + anim.firstFrame` where anim is the `AnimationItem` function. I haven't done anything that sounds quite as complex at what you say. I just used the `playSegments([40,70])` function which reports frames 0 through 29 in enterFrame (not very helpful!).

Comment: There's some mentions of it here: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/2845 and https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/2613 - And I stepped through the code to see for myself before I was able to find these. Lottie docs are a classic case of 'not quite there'. They don't even have an explanation of `currentFrame`.